# Custom fields in backbone model not defined when used in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

I have a model and collection defined in Backbone like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

DeviceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/ajax/mvcDevices',

    validationRules: {
        name: [{ rule: 'required'}],
        mac: [
        { rule: 'required' },
        { rule: 'isMacAddress' }
        ],
        speed: [{ rule: 'required'}]
    },

    preprocess: {
        name: ['clean', 'trim'],
        speed: ['clean', 'trim']
    }
});

DeviceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/ajax/mvcDevices',
    Model: DeviceModel
});
});
```

However, when working with these models inside a Collection, the custom fields listed are all not defined. What have I missed here?

Comment: `Model : DeviceModel` => `model : DeviceModel` ? (lowercase `m`)

Comment: @WiredPrairie (facepalm) It was that, staring me in the face all along. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the `defaults` Model attribute to enforce default values like this:

```
var DeviceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/ajax/mvcDevices',

    defaults: {
        validationRules: {
            name: [{ rule: 'required'}],
            mac: [
            { rule: 'required' },
            { rule: 'isMacAddress' }
            ],
            speed: [{ rule: 'required'}]
        },

        preprocess: {
            name: ['clean', 'trim'],
            speed: ['clean', 'trim']
        }
    }
});

var DeviceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/ajax/mvcDevices',
    Model: DeviceModel
});

var collection = new DeviceCollection();

var model = new DeviceModel({id: 1});
collection.add(model);
console.log(collection.get(1).get('validationRules'));
console.log(collection.get(1).get('preprocess'));
```

From Backbone documentation if you create your model with the `new` operator all properties in `defaults` will get copied to the new object, so it depends on the way you create your model objects.

Comment: Ah.. problem here is these values aren't data items, so I don't want them going in the model attributes and getting sent to the server, etc. They are support data for the validation code to process the model.

Comment: @Nidonocu: In that case, the way you declared them is correct and they should be available as "standard" instance attributes accessible like so, modelInstance.attribute (e.g. modelInstance.validationRules). In other words, don't access them via Backbone.Model's get().